# Can one set a "computed constant" in a Swift `struct`?

Tags: swift

For convenience in naming constants I would like to do the following in Swift (my real case is less trivial) so I could refer to `IntegerConstants.SIX` in later code.  However, `SIX` cannot be given a value because `ONE` and `TWO` do not have values till the `struct` has been initialized .. bit of a "Catch-22"

```
struct IntegerConstants {
   let ONE = 1.0
   let TWO = 2.0
   let SIX = (ONE + TWO) * TWO
}
```

Is there a way to do this, or an equivalent that creates a named constant of the form "`GROUP.VALUE`", that I have not yet discovered?

Comment: [Search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+run+before+%27self%27+is+available) you get from that code and you find your answer.

Comment: FYI, generally it's a good idea to set a constant's value directly in this case, since it will have to be calculated every time an IntegerConstants instance is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using this to group constants, as with `IntegerConstants.six`, what you actually want to do is make them static.  This also solves your error since you don't need to access a `self`.

```
struct IntegerConstants {
    static let one = 1
    static let two = 2
    static let six = (one + two) * two
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two (good) options here as far as I'm concerned.

1. make it a computed property. This is pretty common for this type of thing, the only downside is the calculation is done every time the property is accessed, but as long as it's cheep it shouldn't be a big problem.

   ```
   struct IntegerConstants {
       let ONE = 1.0
       let TWO = 2.0
       var SIX: Double {
          get { return (ONE + TWO) * TWO }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Move your constants outside the struct to be global. This will be identical in behavior to what you want to do, but it adds additional constants.

   ```
   fileprivate let ONE_CONST = 1.0
   fileprivate let TWO_CONST = 2.0
   struct IntegerConstants {
       let ONE = ONE_CONST
       let TWO = TWO_CONST
       let SIX = (ONE_CONST + TWO_CONST) * TWO_CONST
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   fileprivate let ONE_CONST = 1.0
   fileprivate let TWO_CONST = 2.0
   fileprivate let SIX_CONST = (ONE_CONST + TWO_CONST) * TWO_CONST

   struct IntegerConstants {
       let ONE = ONE_CONST
       let TWO = TWO_CONST
       let SIX = SIX_CONST
   }
   ```

Comment: But, in your example (1): "make it a computed property" there is an esoteric problem. If `TWO` were also a computed property the factor `ONE + TWO` would fail because `ONE` is a `Double` and `TWO` is a `() -> Double`, and you can't add those different types!

Comment: A computed property is just like having a function, but syntactically different. TWO would have the Type of Double, and it uses a function to figure out what to return when it's accessed.

Comment: You are correct; I had an extraneous `=` sign in my `var two: Int = { return 2 }`.  With the `=` it assigns a closure to `two`; without, it assigns an `Int` which what I had intended.  Apologies for the red herring.

Answer (score 2):

You sure can, but you need to do it in an initializer:

```
struct IntegerConstants {
   let ONE = 1.0
   let TWO = 2.0
   let SIX: Double

   init() {
        SIX = (ONE + TWO) * TWO
    }
}
```

But there are a few really big issues with this code.

1. The `IntegerConstants` struct actually contains `Double`s
2. Constants like this should be static. There's no reason for them to be bound to an instance.
3. Given that this struct should now only contain static members, making instances of it wouldn't make much sense, so it should be switched to a case-less enum, so that no instances of it can be made.
4. Swift follows the convention of Using `UpperCamelCase` for static members and types. You should follow that `INSTEAD_OF_USING_YELLING_CASE`.
5. The `IntegerConstants` struct and its members should not even exist in the first place. Just use the literals directly! `IntegerConstants.SIX` does not solve the magic number issue. It's just a terrible way of way of just saying `6`.

Comment: You're right, of course, on points (1) and (4). My example suffered from simplification (and translation from a Java example). For point (5), I agree that literal `6` is better in this case but sometimes literals aren't: (a) defining `EarthRadius` all uses of the constant throughout the program to be adjusted [sometime constants need adjusting!] in one place, and (b) where the literal isn't obvious like `EarthRadius` rather than `6378.135`.  I will explore (2) and (3) .. thanks

Comment: @RamsayConsulting `EarthRadius` would make sense. `SIX` would not. The point is to give a meaningful label to otherwise seemingly arbitrary constant to provide more information on it. `SIX` adds no meaningful information over `6`.

Comment: Total agreement!